# Adding a Calculated Row in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am displaying a table in Tableau for toys sales , I want to introduce a calculated row based on the previous row data. How can I do this in Tableau.

```
Toys type   Sales in 2013   Sales in 2014
  type1        10                 15
  type2        20                 13
  type3        30                 28
  type4       X/30               X/28
```

Comment: If you want help, post a small sample of your data or at least describe the columns in your toys table. This kind of problem is routine usually

Answer (score 1):

You can't specifically add one row to your database in Tableau. Calculated fields behave like fields, i.e. new columns.

If you explain what you're trying to achieve with this new row, we might be able to provide a solution. Adding a row, just for the sake of it, is not possible. You would need to manipulate your data source outside Tableau.

One thing you can do is create a calculated field to do that calculation for every row. Simple

```
X / [Toys type]
```

And X can be a number or a parameter